# AMIS30543 | Data-Sheet understanding Status register

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, spi, electronics, stepper

I was reading the data Sheet of AMIS-30543 stepper motor driver and I was not able to understand how to combine the result of the Micro step position status register MSP[8:0]. I know that its a 9 bit value . Help me understand how to get the value.

In the data sheet it is given like

[image: dataSheet]

in SR3 -> MSP[8:2], and in SR4 -> MSP[6:0]. How I am I suppose to get the 9 bit out of these.

---

In the library I have seen that , `(sr3<<2) | (sr4 & 3)`  . I don't understand why they are doing and `&` here.

Please explain . also If there was no library how am I suppose to know how to combine these registers from the dataSheet .

Link to [DataSheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AMIS-30543-D.PDF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the data is duplicated between the registers. Both registers contain MSP[6:2].

If MSP contains `111001001` the registers (ignoring the MSB "PAR" bit) would look like:

```
SR3: 1110010
SR4: 1001001
```

If we line those up it's then like:

```
SR3: 1110010
SR4    1001001
```

You can now see the overlap.

So taking SR3 and shifting it left two places (`sr3 << 2`) gives you:

```
SR3:   1110010
<<2: 111001000
```

Taking the lowest two bits of SR4 with `& 3` gives you:

```
SR4:   1001001
& 3:   0000001
```

Then ORing the two results together:

```
SR3<<2: 111001000
SR4 &3: 000000001
-----------------
MSP   : 111001001
```

Comment: How can I understand this from data sheet like from sr3 and sr4

Comment: The 8:2 and 6:0 refer to the range of bits stored in that register. It's a little unusual to have overlap like that.

Comment: So is it okay to do like :: ‘(sr3 << 2 | sr4)’

Comment: No, because of the PAR bit that's in the MSB that will corrupt SR3.

Comment: Ohh ok. I understand now .

Comment: Again one more doubt this overlapping of bits you came to know by practice and experience or you read some where ?

Comment: Practice and experience. It's the first time I have seen overlapping bits like that, but the code snippet you showed and the 8:2 and 6:0 in the datasheet allowed me to infer it. It's really not clear at all in the datasheet, so it's not surprising you were struggling with it.